# Extract vectors from a list based on given elements

Tags: r

Suppose I have vector v contains 6 elements  and a  list with a number of  vectors, each vector  has two elements  the list has been generated from the matrix m as below:

```
v<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

m = matrix( c(1, 2, 10 , 2, 1, 3, 8 ,9,4,6,3,1,9,11,4,7,12,3,2,5),  ncol=2, byrow = TRUE) 

l <-tapply(m,rep(1:nrow(m),ncol(m)),function(i)i)
>  l
$`1`
[1] 1 2

$`2`
[1] 10  2

$`3`
[1] 1 3

$`4`
[1] 8 9

$`5`
[1] 4 6

$`6`
[1] 3 1

$`7`
[1]  9 11

$`8`
[1] 4 7

$`9`
[1] 12  3

$`10`
[1] 2 5
```

From the list `l`, I want to keep  only the vectors which    have  the two elements in  `v`

The result will be similar to:

```
>  R
 $`1`
 [1] 1 2

 $`2`
 [1] 1 3

 $`3`
 [1] 4 6

 $`4`
 [1] 3 1

 $`5`
 [1] 2 5
```

The original list has 18835 vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to check if all the elements in `x` are present in `v`, assuming you have only 2 elements in each list element.

```
l[sapply(l, function(x) all(x %in% v))]


#$`1`
#[1] 1 2

#$`3`
#[1] 1 3

#$`5`
#[1] 4 6

#$`6`
#[1] 3 1

#$`10`
#[1] 2 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we use `sapply` with `simplify=T` to make a boolean vector that we can use to subset `l`. The assumptions I've made are that each list has two elements, but this could easily be changed by changing `sum` to `all` with minor edits.

```
l[sapply(l,function(x){sum(x %in% v)==2},simplify = T)]
```